# sed command to exclude specific lines in file between range of pattern

Tags: unix, awk, sed

I want to do substitution using sed command, but also this should not get applied to specific range of lines matching some pattern/word.

File has below lines:

```
startline1
top
nice
good
bad
nice
nice
verybad
Extremely bad
bad
nice
endline1
nice
```

Trail from my end:
**`sed -i '/startline1/,/endline1/ s/nice/decent/'`**
The substitute must happen between `startline1` and `endline1`
But must exclude the update between `bad` and `verybad` words

With the above command I get result as below:

```
startline1
top
decent
good
bad
decent
decent
verybad
Extremely bad
bad
decent
endline1
nice
```

- This will do a replacement between only `startline1` and `endline1`, which is as expected.
- But now I don't want the update to happen between `bad` and `verybad`.

**Expected Result:**

```
startline1
top
decent
good
bad
nice
nice
verybad
Extremely bad
bad
decent
endline1
nice
```

Any suggestion on this would be of help.

Comment: Why sed and not awk?

Comment: Do you really want the bullet chars and numbers in your data, or is that just the only way you could find to display you data line-by-line? (I understand, kind of frustrating for newbies). Good luck.

Comment: no need of bullet or numbers.

Comment: awk i haven't tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following based on your shown samples. Tested successfully in link
https://ideone.com/zFl8LK

```
awk '
/^bad$/{
 bad_found=1
}
/^verybad$/{
 bad_found=""
}
/endline1/{
  found=""
}
/startline1/{
  found=1
}
found && !bad_found{
  sub(/nice/,"decent")
}
1
' Input_file
```

***Explanation*:** Firstly checking condition if line starts with `bad` set `bad_found` then checking if line starts with `verybad` then unset `bad_found` there
checking condition if a line contains `endline1` then unset `found`(found variable work is explained further in explanation). Then checking condition if line contains `startline1` then setting variable `found` here. Then checking condition if `found` is set AND variable `bad_found` is NOT SET then substitute nice with decent in that line(where found makes sure that we are boundaries of startling to endline). Finally mentioning `1` will print all lines.

***Note:*** in case your Input_file's lines may have more than 1 occurrence of `nice` then change `sub` to `gsub` in above code.

Comment: This does not reproduce the required output i.e. the last occurrence of `nice` should be `decent` because there is no following `verybad` preceding the last `bad`. Otherwise `sed '/start/,/end/{/bad/,/verybad/b;s/nice/decent/}' file` would fit the bill.

Comment: @potong, hello sir, last occurrence is nice when I run my code for given samples please check link https://ideone.com/zFl8LK I have mentioned it and written this as per shown samples only sir.

Comment: In the solution you asked me to check, line 11 of stdin is `nice` and still `nice` following processing the OP stated expected result for line 11 to change from `nice` to `decent` as it falls between `start` and `end` but not between `bad` and `verybad`. `verybad` must be present for lines to be excluded from substitution and therefore cannot be determined by reading a line at a time, it must be looked for ahead.

Comment: @potong, ohh not sure how missed it, apologies, will fix it in sometime, thank you for letting me know sir and++ for your code thank you again.

Comment: @potong,  sed '/start/,/end/{/bad/,/verybad/b;s/nice/decent/}' file, This also helped. thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/\n/bb;/^start/{:a;N;/^end/M!ba;:b;/^bad.*verybad/h;x;/./{/^verybad/z;s/[^\n]*\n//;x;P;D};x;s/^nice/decent/;P;D}' file
```

The lines between `start` and `end` are gathered up and then processed a line at a time.

If the pattern space contains multiple lines i.e. the lines have already been gathered up, a flag is set in the hold space by copying the current pattern space if the first of these lines contains `bad` and there follows a line that contains `verybad`.

If the hold space is not empty and first line is `verybad` the hold space is emptied, thus flipping the `s/nice/decent/` on.

N.B. The solution uses the control flow that the `D` command resumes processing the current multi line until the pattern space is empty.

If more that one `nice` occurs on a line use the idiom:

```
`:c;s/^\([^\n]*\)nice/\1decent/;tc`
```